# flutter: Error output from Xcode build (Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 13.)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            4.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-07-29 16:06:43.628 xcodebuild[13516:6587696] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-07-29 16:06:43.628 xcodebuild[13516:6587696] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/bw/tjsx710n72967mmwkx1g78p80000gn/T/flutter_tools.EaTTtg/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirE4C8sG/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "fonts/Arima-Regular.ttf".
    Failed to package /Users//Desktop/development/flutter apps/learn.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/bw/tjsx710n72967mmwkx1g78p80000gn/T/flutter_tools.EaTTtg/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirE4C8sG/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited
```

This problem always confronts me, no matter what I try to do or what code I write, what is the solution?

Always only when I turn on the device for the first time does the simulator work so even if I stopped programming, I would keep the simulator open for days until I finish the code because if I close it will not work again and I will not see my code result. it's for me a big problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

Open the xcworkspace file in Xcode. Select products and click on clean build folder. Clear the warnings if you get any. Run the app from Xcode. Once its successfully built from Xcode you should be able to run it from your IDE too

Comment: the build failed what should I do now ??

Comment: "fonts/Arima-Regular.ttf". replace this font file.. Its not being fetched.. Clean pods. remove Podfile.lock and then do pod install.. Then try again from Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's good to know what is going on in native code as well (ios). However if you just starting with Flutter and do not want to do anything with XCode there is one really easy way how to fix it.

Just create new flutter project using terminal commend `flutter create <project_name>`

And copy the `ios` folder from this new project to your existing one where you have this problem.
Then it should work.

This way is a little bit problematic if you made some changes in native code e.g: you changed your `info.plist` file. Then you do not have these changes any more - then you should consider fix it using XCode.

Comment: deleting ios folder and running flutter create . command do the same trick